# Woocommerce Product Variations with Link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the category I'm trying to show the variation of each product underneath it with a link for each variation.

Currently I have all the text outputting but cannot fathom how to get the link. I'm not great at PHP so apologies if I'm being really stupid.

Here's what I have so far which was cobbled together from some advice I found around and tweaked.

*Thank you in advance.*

```
if($product->is_type('variable')){
    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        

        $attributes = array();
        foreach( $variation['attributes'] as $key => $value ){
            $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $key );
            $taxonomy_label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
            $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy )->name;
            $attributes[] = $term_name;
        }
        echo '
            '.implode( ' | ', $attributes ).'';

       
        $active_price = floatval($variation['display_price']); // Active price
        $regular_price = floatval($variation['display_regular_price']); // Regular Price
        if( $active_price != $regular_price ){
            $sale_price = $active_price; // Sale Price
        }
        echo '
           '.$variation['price_html'].'

        ';
    }
};
```

[image: Image Variation]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `get_permalink()` function by giving it the variation id to retrieve the permalink for your variation.

The attributes are saved in the `$variation` so you can simply use `implode( ' | ', $variation['attributes'] )`. No need to retrieve them again.

Also the part where you are checking sale price versus regular price doesn't seem to do a whole lot since you are choosing to go with `$variation['price_html']` in the end. If you simply want to display the current (sale) price I would use `$variation['display_price']` in combination with the `wc_price()` function to get the correct format for your price.

Lastly you can better use `printf()` to create a formatted output instead of echoing out each variable, one after another.

In total your code should look something like this:

```
if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {
        printf( '<a href="%s"><p class="variation">%s %s</p></a>', get_permalink( $variation['variation_id'] ), implode( ' | ', $variation['attributes'] ), wc_price( $variation['display_price'] ) );
    }
}
```